# Mapping enums while using dapper

Tags: enums, dapper

I have the following problem. I am using Dapper to connect to a database, the field that is a varchar in the database is an enum in my object. There is no problem for Dapper to map the database object to my DTO if the enum has the same name as the string in the database. Unfortunately, the strings in the database are not very user friendly and I was wondering if there is a way to map them or convert (only enums) to use more user friendly versions. For example, database value for a field:

```
SomeVeIRdLooking_Value
```

And I would like it to map to:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    MyFormattedValue
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a scenario dapper supports currently. It supports numeric conversion and direct name conversion. I will check the code when I'm at a PC though

Answer (score 0):

You can select string values from database and convert it by hand.

```
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        None,
        Success,
        Failure
    }

    var enums = connection.Query<string>("select 'None' union select 'Success' union select 'Failure'")
            .Select(x => Enum.Parse(typeof (MyEnum), x)) //use your own method to parse enum from string
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I am looking for. The query is a select * from... and there are multiple enums in there.

Answer (score 0):

This is nearly 8 years later, but in case this helps someone else, you can correct "bad" database values with the query

```
SELECT *, 
 CASE DbColumnName 
  WHEN 'SomeVeIRdLooking_Value'
  THEN 'MyFormattedValue'
  WHEN 'SomeOtherWierd_Value'
  THEN 'MyOtherFormattedValue'
  ELSE  DbColumnName
 END AS DbColumnNameFix
```